# How to return a URL of uploaded image

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Try to get URL of image uploaded in Firebase Storage, using this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0#get_a_download_url), but there's no info about how to return `downloadUri` value from `Task.continueWithTask` method.

Even [method documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/tasks) doesn't helped to understand.

Quote from docs, there's no explanation how to get this URL:

After uploading a file, you can get a URL to download the file by calling the getDownloadUrl() method on the StorageReference:

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg");
        uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                return ref.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                } else {
                    // Handle failures
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: It looks like you've written code that gets the download URL, so I don't really understand what the problem is here.

Comment: I re-writed [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54785290/continuewithtask-method-doesnt-start), the problem is that `continueWithTask` doesn't start. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Firebase for a while, but the way I used to do it is to assign either a `SuccessListener` or `OnCompleteListener` after calling `ref.getDownloadUrl()`

> Example

```
ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(url -> {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the URL of the image or the data you have stored in firestore you should use OnSuccessListener

Like

```
     firepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {     
@Override

public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

    firepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

@Override
public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
final String url = uri.toString();
 }});});
```

Here string URL will have the link of the image or the video