# ignoring continueWithTask method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

When you click a button, a photo from the gallery is taken (`addPhoto` method).

In the onActivityResult method, the photo is uploaded to Firebase Storage with the name of the key (`donosId` variable) received.

Then, [according to the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files?authuser=0#get_a_download_url), to obtain the URL of the image, We use the `continueWithTask` method, inside which the resulting URL is placed in the Firebase Database.

Problem: the `continueWithTask` method does not start (checked with logs + the URL value remains null). What is the error or how else can you return from the URL method (a variable of type Uri)?

Code:

```
public void addPhoto(View view) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 1 && data != null) {

            final DatabaseReference newDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("items").push();

            donosId = newDatabaseReference.getKey();

            final StorageReference imageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("images/" + donosId + ".jpg");

            imageRef.putFile(data.getData()).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                    return imageRef.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

                        String var = downloadUri.toString();

                        Item item = new Item(mNameEditText.getText().toString(),
                                mSecNameEditText.getText().toString(), var,
                                (int) System.currentTimeMillis());
                        newDatabaseReference.setValue(item);

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

I don't know why the function isn't running inside and can't access downloadURL, but the image gets uploaded to Firebase Storge.